# Recuperar Valor Array

Tags: javascript

tenho um array de strings.
Estou tentando recuperar o valor de location, mas não estou conseguindo.
Deem uma olhada no codigo:

```js
 var cord = ["-19.45738,-44.2416695"];
  
  for(var i = 0; i<cord.length; i++){
        var location = cord[i].split[","];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
        map: map
    });
         
       
    }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que precisa de for?

Answer (score 7):

O que está errado é o split:

```
var location = cord[i].split(",");
```

`split` é uma função, usa-se parênteses.